# Explicit Expression for Linear Transformation of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. Consider the following transformed matrix $A_{t}$, where all off diagonal entries of $A$ remain the same, but the diagonal entries are given by $$[A_{t}]_{ii}=t[A]_{ii}$$ where $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Is there an easy method for finding matrices $M_{1}(t)$ and $M_{2}(t)$ such that $A_{t}=M_{1}(t)AM_{2}(t)$. Since the transformation taking $A$ to $A_{t}$ is linear, acts only on $n$ entries and has essentially $1$ degree of freedom, I suspect that such matrices should exist.

Comment: When you say *Since the transformation taking $A$ to $A_{t}$ is linear such matrices should exist*, this is not at all evident. A linear map operating on the space of the real matrices $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ should have $n^2 \times n^2$ entries. While two matrices $M_1,M_2 \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ will only provide $ 2 \times n^2$ coefficients. This is not proof that the problem doesn't have a solution... But at least we need to be cautious.

Comment: Fair enough, is the problem better posed if we restrict attention to $A$ symmetric?

Comment: Your point is appreciated, I did overlook it completely. I will edit the question so as to remove the false conclusion.

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, do you expect the identity $[A_{t}]_{ii}=t[A]_{ii}
$ to hold for any square matrix $A$?

Comment: This is how I define the transformed matrix $A_t$, so I would not call it an identity. But yes, the transformation is applicable to any square matrix.

Comment: First, if $\det A=0,$ it is possible that $\det A_t\neq 0.$ For example $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $A_t$ has determinant zero only when $t=\pm 1.$ So there can be no $M_1(t),M_2(t)$ for $t\neq \pm 1.$

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I=\{i\mid A_{ii}=0\}=\{i_1,i_2,\dots i_k\}.$ If $k>0,$ define $B_{mn}=A_{i_mi_n},$ a $k\times k$ matrix.

Then if $\det A=0$ and either $I$ is empty or $\det B\neq 0,$ then $\det A_t$ is a polynomial of degree $n-k,$ with lead coefficient $\pm \det B,$ or $1$ when $k=0.$

So $\det A_t\neq 0$ for all but finitely many $t.$

But when $\det A_t\neq 0,$ there can be no such $M_1,M_2.$

Example when $I$ is empty:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Example when $I$ is non-empty:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

---

When $\det A\neq 0$ you can find many examples. If $M(t)$ is a parameterized set of invertible matrices, we can use: $$M_{1}(t)=A_tM(t)^{-1}A^{-1},M_2(t)=M(t)$$
and:
$$M_1(t)=M(t), M_2(t)=A^{-1}M(t)^{-1}A_t.$$

We can take $M(t)=I$ for a trivial example.