# When can a linear transformation on the space of $n\times n$ matrices be written as a product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This question is a generalization of a previous question of mine. Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ denote the space of $n \times n$ matrices with real entries, and let $\mathcal{T}:M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\to M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a linear map. What are the conditions that $\mathcal{T}$ needs to satisfy so that we may find matrices $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ such that the following holds $$\mathcal{T}(A)=T_{1}AT_{2}$$

The prior question was [Explicit Expression for Linear Transformation of a Matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4238313/explicit-expression-for-linear-transformation-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment8809844_4238313), and a comment there made me curious as to what can be said more generally.

Comment: A very basic necessary condition is that there must be a real $k$ such that $\det \mathcal T(A)=k \det A.$

Comment: The set of all linear transformations on the matrices is of dimension $n^4,$ while the subset of cases for which an $M_1,M_2$ exists is of dimension $2n^2.$ So it is certainly a small subset of such $\mathcal T.$

Comment: I should have said “at most $2n^2$ in the last comments, since two different pairs $M_1,M_2$ can give the same $\mathcal T.$

Comment: Another basic necessary condition is that $\mathrm{rank}(\mathcal{T}(A)) \leq \mathrm{rank}(A)$ for every $A$.

Comment: The subset of such $\mathcal T$ is not a subspace of the vector space of all linear transformations. It’s closed under scaling, but not under addition. I don’t think it is a sub-manifold, either, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Dan Interestingly, it can be shown (if I remember correctly) that such rank-decreasing transformations (sometimes called "linear preservers" of rank) must have the the form $\mathcal T(A) = M_1AM_2$ or $\mathcal T(A) = M_1A^\top M_2$.

Comment: Technically, these are preservers if $\det \mathcal TA=\det A$ for all $A.$ So, when $T_1,T_2$ are non-singular, you need to scale $\mathcal T$ to get a preserver. If either $T_1,T_2$ is singular, you can’t scale them. @BenGrossmann https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695268

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the correction

Comment: A (strong) sufficient condition: if $\mathcal{T}$ is a nonzero *algebra* endomorphism, then it is an inner automorphism, so there is $B$ with $\mathcal{T}(A)=BAB^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

A caveat: I am *fairly* sure about all statements made here, but I have not checked in detail. If you like, treat this answer as an educated conjecture.

In a nutshell, the answer is as follows. Given the matrix $[\mathcal T]_{\mathcal B}$ of the transformation (relative to a certain basis of $M_n(\Bbb R))$, there exists a permutation $\phi:M_n(\Bbb R) \to M_n(\Bbb R)$ of the matrix entries such that $\mathcal T$ can be expressed in the desired form if and only if $\phi([\mathcal T]_{\mathcal B})$ has rank $1$ (or less).

---

Let $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denote the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $E_{ij} = e_ie_j^T$. Let $\mathcal B$ denote the basis given by the set of matrices $E_{ij}$ where the tuples $(i,j)$ are taken in [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order). Notably, the coordinate vector of a matrix $A$ is given by $[A]_{\mathcal B} = \operatorname{vec}(A)$, where $\operatorname{vec}$ denotes the [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator.

If $\mathcal T(A) = T_1AT_2$, then the matrix of $\mathcal T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is given by
$$
[\mathcal T]_{\mathcal B} = T_1 \otimes T_2^\top.
$$
Given a transformation $\mathcal T$ over $M_n(\Bbb R)$, the matrix of $\mathcal T$ can be computed as follows. Let $E_1,E_2,\dots,E_{n^2}$ be an enumeration of the elements of $\mathcal B$ (in order). Then, for any matrix $A$, we have $\mathcal T(A) = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}([\mathcal T]_{\mathcal B}\operatorname{vec}(A)),$ and the $i$th column of $[\mathcal T]_{\mathcal B}$ is given by $\operatorname{vec}(\mathcal T(E_i))$.

Now, given the matrix $M = [\mathcal T]_\mathcal B$, the question is whether there exist matrices $A,B \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ such that $M = A \otimes B$. To that end, we define a linear map $\phi:M_n(\Bbb R) \to M_n(\Bbb R)$ as follows. For any column-vectors $u,v,x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, we want to have
$$
\phi((uv^T) \otimes (xy^T)) = (u x^T) \otimes (v y^T).
$$
Notably, we have
$$
\operatorname{vec}((uv^T) \otimes (xy^T)) = \operatorname{vec}((u \otimes x)(v \otimes y)^T) = u \otimes x \otimes v \otimes y\\
\operatorname{vec}(\phi((uv^T) \otimes (xy^T))) = \operatorname{vec}[(u \otimes v)(x \otimes y)^T] = u \otimes v \otimes x \otimes y.
$$
In terms of the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), the matrix $[\phi]_{\mathcal B}$ may thus be computed as
$$
[\phi]_{\mathcal B} = \sum_{i,j,p,q = 1}^n (e_i \otimes e_j \otimes e_p \otimes e_q)(e_i \otimes e_p \otimes e_j \otimes e_q)^T
\\ = 
\sum_{i,j,p,q = 1}^n E_{ii} \otimes E_{jp} \otimes E_{pj} \otimes E_{qq}.
$$
It turns out that $M$ can be written in the form $M = A \otimes B$ for $A,B \in M_n(\Bbb R)$ if and only if $\phi(M)$ can be written in the form $M = uv^T$ for $u,v \in \Bbb R^{n^2}$, which is to say that $\phi(M)$ has rank at most $1$. If $\phi(M)$ can be written as $\phi(M) = uv^T$ for such $u,v$, then $A,B$ can be obtained by
$$
A = \operatorname{vec}(u), \quad B = \operatorname{vec}(v).
$$