# write a matrix as a single kronecker product?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I came across a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix} a& b& 0& 0\\0& 0& c& d\end{bmatrix}$. At first glance, I kinda felt it can be written as a Kronecker product. I tried doing so but the best that I can do is the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\otimes[a\ b]+\begin{bmatrix}0& 0\\0& 1\end{bmatrix}\otimes [c \ d]. $$

Is there a way to write this as a single Kronecker product?

I'm using Horn & Johnson's Kronecker product $A\otimes B=[a_{ij}B]$. I don't prescribe the size of the factors except it has to be smaller than the original to avoid $A=A\otimes[1]$ in the comments. If it can be written like so, then either the factors are

1. $2\times 2$ and $1\times 2$
2. $2\times 1$ and $1\times 4$.

My attempt was under case 1). Can it be improved? If not, can one do it in case 2)?

Comment: [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition) must be assembled from multiples of a single smaller block. There is no such block here except for the trivial $1\times1$ block  with $A=A\otimes[1]$.

Comment: Of course they have to be smaller sizes as my attempt shows.

Comment: So it isn't a Kronecker product except in the trivial sense.

Comment: The terms are 2-by-4 if $A\otimes B=[a_{ij}B]$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Simple tensors are examples that don't satisfy your claim.

Comment: Which claim? There is no $B$ in your case of size larger than $1\times1$ for generic $a,b,c,d$. If $[a\ b]$ and $[c\ d]$ are proportional then you can do it as in the answer below.

Comment: @chhro [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4240982/81360) address  a similar concern. For your case: the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{m_{11} & \cdots & m_{14}\\ m_{21} & \cdots & m_{24}}
$$
can be written as a Kronecker product $M = A \otimes B$ with $A$ of size $2 \times 2$ and $B$ of size $2 \times 1$ if and only if the rearranged matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{12}\\ m_{13} & m_{14}\\ m_{21} & m_{22} \\ m_{23} & m_{24}}
$$
has rank $1$.

Answer (score 1):

It can only be done if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are linearly dependent. Say $(c,d)=\lambda(a,b)$. Then
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}\otimes\begin{pmatrix}a&b\end{pmatrix}.$$