# How to get the inverse of Kronecker self-product (Kronecker square root)

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse, kronecker-product

I am basically trying to solve for $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ below, such that for any vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and some fixed $C \in \mathbb{R}^{m^2 \times n^2}$:

$$ (M \otimes M) \mathbf{x} = C \mathbf{x}$$

If there is a unique solution, I guess this is the same as finding $M$ such that $(M \otimes M) = C$.

Are there conditions under which there are solutions? Any knowledge about this problem would be useful, as I'm not too familiar with it; does it have a name? Are there certain fields where solving for M like this comes up?

Edit: first version of the question incorrectly stated C was square and symmetric.

Comment: The equality only holds for all vectors $\mathbf x$ if $M \otimes M = C$. In order for $M\otimes M$ and $C$ to have the same shape, $M$ must be $n \times n$.

Comment: You might find [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4241059/81360) to be helpful

Comment: Since $C$ is symmetric, it must be square. Likewise, $A=(M\otimes M-C)$ must also be square, i.e. $\,m=n.\,$ Writing the equation as
$$Ax = 0$$
the task is to find vectors in the nullspace of $A$, or equivalently eigenvectors of $A$ associated with a zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the answers. I think I got confused when I was asking the question. So in this case, M is not square. I was incorrect in saying that C is symmetric or even square however. I got confused by something else. I'm sorry about that, it changes the question completely.

Comment: It appears that you want the [Kronecker square root](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.8149) of the $C$ matrix.

Comment: Ah yes, seems like it. I didn't know the term for it.